# Publishing to live, changing localdb to SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, localdb

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 3 application locally and now I'm wanting to publish it to windows azure server (which is all set up fine within my account) so that it is accessible by anyone.

However I'm having issues as the database used in the application and the connection strings in web.config are localdb.

How do I go about changing localdb to SQL database so that I can host the website live properly? 
Do I just need to change the connection strings or is there further configuration required on the server or in the application?

Comment: At the very least you will need to change the connection strings as you suspect.  Do that and see what happens.

Comment: Can you post your connection string (removing the sensitive bits obviously)?

Comment: Which database server do you want to use?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Just change the connection string from localdb to SQL Server.